# Calculate double integral (not sure what im doing wrong)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$ \int \int (4x)/(1+xy) dA      
R = [0,4] \times [0,1] $

I intgrated by y first and got $(4ln(1+xy) |_(1,0))$

Which got me $4ln(1+x)$

Then integrated by x and got (4(1+x)ln(1+x) - x |(4,0)

And got the answer 20ln(5) - 4

Though my homework module says that's incorrect.

Any thoughts? Thanks for reading BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to distribute the 4. So you should have a -16 instead of a -4.

Comment: Excellent catch, I'll have to be more careful next time I integrate natural log.

Comment: Yea you always need to be looking out for the simple mistakes!